# Python script able to download pdf from web but it creates corrupt document

Tags: python, pdf, request

I am using following python script to download pdf file from web. I can able to download it but when I am trying to open it it shows corrupt and not able to open it.

Could you please help me in this regard?

Script:

```
import requests
url = 'https://docview.payableslockbox.com/docview/pInvoiceImage.aspx?i=24226286&docId=55303882&c=PINNACLE&s=da88d87c-c2fb-c120-9ae3-be0001691de3'
response=requests.get(url)
expdf=response.content
egpdf=open("C:\\Python\\Projects\\PDFDownload\\Test\\files111.pdf",'wb')
egpdf.write(expdf)
egpdf.close()
```

Comment: If you download it directly from your browser, can you see if the pdf is fine ?

Comment: Download from the browser and compare the results, so you'll have a clue of the problem

Comment: What's in `files111.pdf` if you open it in a text editor such as notepad.exe?

Comment: Your script works fine with a "standard" pdf, e.g. ` url="https://bugs.python.org/file47781/Tutorial_EDIT.pdf"`. So @KJ's comment is the clue.

Comment: @Pac0- PDF is fine I have checked at browser

Comment: @KJ - Yeah we need to first do the user login and then we have to download a file.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel- Yeah it shows HTML code when I open pdf in notepad.

Comment: @Demi-Lune- it is able to download any standard pdf file .

Comment: I might be wrong about this but I don't think you can just open a PDF file in UTF-8, copy it over, and create a new file. You'll have to download the actual file for it to work.